# Generation of all k-combinations of a set in max-differing order

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, permutations

I'm looking for an algorithm that generates all k-combinations of a set, such that each successive combination generated differs as much as possible (or in practice, a lot) from all previous combinations.

For example, given the set `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`, I might get something like the following:

```
    {1, 2, 3}
    {4, 5, 6}
    {1, 2, 4}
    {3, 5, 6}
    {1, 4, 6}
    {2, 3, 5}
    {1, 4, 5}
    {2, 3, 6}
    {1, 5, 6}
    {2, 3, 4}
    {1, 2, 5}
    {3, 4, 6}
    {1, 2, 6}
    {3, 4, 5}
    {1, 3, 6}
    {2, 4, 5}
    {1, 3, 5}
    {2, 4, 6}
    {1, 3, 4}
    {2, 5, 6}
```

I'm aware that using Gray codes would effectively give me the opposite of what I want... unfortunately, it's not obvious to me how I would be able to reverse the Gray code algorithm to produce something similar to my desired output.

Is there a known algorithm that would suit my needs?

Comment: "all k-combinations of a set". Since [(n, k) Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code) is about permutations, can you confirm that you are talking about subset here?  "Each successive combination generated differs as much as possible". Can you give a numerical definition of the difference between two combinations?

Comment: When $k = n/2$ (with $n$ being the universe size), try complementing every other set.

Comment: A clearer criterion can be the fairness requirement: Any element cannot appear two times more than any other person at any time of generation.